# Rotating Images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I realise this is all over the internet, but I can't actually find one that I know how to use. I'm very new to JS, and still pretty new to HTML. The most useful thing I've found is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jb9d0es3/3/), except I don't know how to actually implement it into my code. Based on something else I found, I tried this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styling/style.css">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var image = document.getElementById("img1");
        var src = ["concert2.gif", "concert3.gif", "concert4.gif", "concert5.gif", "concert1.gif"];
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <img id="img1" src="concert1.gif" alt="concert1.gif">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var step = 0
        
        function slideit() {
            image.src = src[step];
            image.alt = src[step];
            if (step < 4) {
                step++;
                } else {
                    step = 1;
                    }
        }
        setInterval(slideit, 5000);
    </script>
</body>
```

It didn't work, it just stayed at concert1.gif. Some help would really be appreciated!

-Thanks

Comment: You're trying to make a carousel right ?

Comment: Please keep searching. There are thousands of these on SO alone. Here's a few: [Change image in HTML page every few seconds](//stackoverflow.com/q/13975891), [An infinite carousel with vanilla JavaScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/39673540), [Image change every 30 seconds - loop](//stackoverflow.com/q/3264739), etc. Check your console for errors. There is likely an error "Cannot set property "src" of undefined" or something similar, since you are trying to get `img1` before the page has loaded.

Comment: First of all, put all of your script code to the bottom of <body>, image variable will be empty if you do it like this (because you are accessing <img> before it is even created).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you are trying to retrieve image element before it's loaded in the first script tag. Also language='javascript' is no longer required as JavaScript is now the only scripting language.

Here is your code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styling/style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <img id="img1" src="concert1.gif" alt="concert1.gif">
        <script>
            var image = document.getElementById("img1");
            var src = ["concert2.gif", "concert3.gif", "concert4.gif", "concert5.gif", "concert1.gif"];

            var step = 0
    
            function slideit() {
                image.src = src[step];
                image.alt = src[step];
                if (step < 4) {
                    step++;
                    } else {
                        step = 1;
                        }
            }
            setInterval(slideit, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
```

It still doesn't show up anything because maybe your src is not correct. But, you can still see alt attribute changing. LoL ;)